# Filter a Recyclerview using data from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, filtering

In an app that I'm doing I have this Recyclerview that will let the user see all the datas in my items class. Also, the Recyclerview can be filtered accordingly depending on the  types of trait the user selects in another activity called find_item.activity. So the transfer of data from find_item activity to the results activity is fine but the problem now is in the filtering the recyclerview part. 
For the filtering Im using this methods.

```
public void viewResult(String hair, String color)
{
    hair=hair.toLowerCase();
    color=size.toLowerCase();
    new_list=new ArrayList<>();

    for(finditem_getItems items:arrayList)
    {
        if(items.getHair().toLowerCase().matches(hair) && items.getColor().toLowerCase().matches(color))
        {

            if(!(items.getHair().toLowerCase().contains(hair) && !(items.getColor().toLowerCase().contains(color)))){
                results.setText("Search not found");
            }
            else
            {
                new_list.add(items);
            }
        }
        else if(items.getHair().toLowerCase().matches(hair))
        {                     
             new_list.add(items);                  
        }

    }
    arrayList.clear();
    adapter.filterSearch(new_list);
}
```

And this is the method I use in the adapter class to filter the arraylist

```
public void filterSearch(ArrayList<findpet_getItems> searchLlist){
    arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.clear();
    arrayList.addAll(searchLlist);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In the 1st method I use the datas from the other activity as parameter and use it to filter the recyclerview but it seems somethings wrong in the implementation of my filter method.

Now the problem is if the the search items doesn't exist it doesn't trigger the error statement and if the search item does exist but the two parameters doesn't match each other it just shows all the data that matches the data of the given search selection.

Can anyone tell me if what is it im doing wrong on the filtering side.

Answer (score 1):

What i get from question this must resolve it .

```
 public void viewResult(String hair, String color) {
    hair = hair.toLowerCase();
    color = size.toLowerCase();
    new_list = new ArrayList<>();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(hair)  || TextUtils.isEmpty(color)){
        // To handle the case if search filers are blank
        // show the original complete list 
        new_list.addAll(arrayList);
    }else {
        for (finditem_getItems items : arrayList) {
            if (items.getHair().toLowerCase().matches(hair) || items.getColor().toLowerCase().matches(color)) 
                new_list.add(items);
        }
    }
    arrayList.clear();
    adapter.filterSearch(new_list);
    if(new_list.size==0){
        results.setText("Search not found");
    }else{
        results.setText("");
    }
}
```

Change the code inside loop as per your need cause i am not aware of your searching strategy.

**Update**: to answer to your second question

```
 public void viewResult(String hair, String color) {
    hair = hair.toLowerCase();
    color = size.toLowerCase();
    new_list = new ArrayList<>();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(hair)  && TextUtils.isEmpty(color)){
        // To handle the case if search filers are blank
        // show the original complete list
        new_list.addAll(arrayList);
    }else {
        for (finditem_getItems items : arrayList) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(hair)  && !TextUtils.isEmpty(color)){
                if (items.getHair().toLowerCase().matches(hair) && items.getColor().toLowerCase().matches(color))
                    new_list.add(items);
            }else {
                if (items.getHair().toLowerCase().matches(hair) || items.getColor().toLowerCase().matches(color))
                    new_list.add(items);
            }
        }
    }
    arrayList.clear();
    adapter.filterSearch(new_list);
    if(new_list.size==0){
        results.setText("Search not found");
    }else{
        results.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: its working but i do have a question if you don't mind. if two search item selected for example hair is "long" and  color is "Red"  i want to filter the recyclerview with items that matches this two only.  how can i do that?

Comment: I tried to add this statement in the code you've given which is this if (items.getHair().toLowerCase().matches(hair) && items.getColor().toLowerCase().matches(color)) {
                new_list.add(items);
            }  but it seems not working because it also triggers the 1st statement where all the items that has the same hair or same color appears.

Comment: this will be a different case so you have to first check if search arguments are two or one .

Comment: Im actually still new in java and android so im not sure how to implement it. ahmm if you don't mind can you explain how can I do it.

Comment: I have updated answer . see if work . Debug the code to analyze the process .

Comment: Im sorry but it still show the other items that share the same hair or the same color.

Comment: This you have to debug . Because I am not aware of search stretegy . I did my part . Thx

Comment: Have you find out the issue yet ??